# Sitecore web database indexing lags behind

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, solrcloud

We are using Sitecore 8 with Solrcloud and one of the things we have noticed is that anytime several hundred articles are published the web database indexing lags behind. There never seems to be an issue with the master database indexes.

For web database, the strategy being used is publishasync and for master database indexes it is syncmaster.

Are there any configuration changes that can be made to speed up the web indexing. There aren't really that many items that Sitecore needs to get backed up.

We have taken a few steps to rectify the web database situation -
1. Set all CD indexing to manual.
2. Turned off any unnecessary indexes.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How long is the lag? Does everything eventually get indexed or does it fail?

Comment: All the web indexes get backed up only when there is a lot of activity on the CM like multiple publishes fired off by users. We use workflows on everything. Otherwise, a couple of publishes is not a bother.

Everything eventually gets indexes when indexing catches up.

Comment: Ok, take a look at this blog post I often use it to diagnose issues with indexes. In particular I've had issues with jobs being created unnecessarily and overloading the CM server and auto publish on items set to deep - https://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2014/05/07/how-to-fix-that-burning-smell-coming-from-your-sitecore-search-index/.  There is an UpdateJobThrottle setting that might be of interest also explained in the post.

Comment: I tried comments in that blog post. None of the suggestions were helpful. Is there anyway to raise the priority of these indexing jobs and is that even a viable workaround? The reason I ask is because all the indexing jobs have BelowNormal priority and that makes me think that the indexes are being forced to process after higher priority indexes.